# counter is not incrementing in php mysqli

Tags: php

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_POST['ans'] == $_POST['quiz']){
                $answer++;
            }else{
                $count++;
            }
        }
```

Hello i want to create a quiz so i am going in a correct way 
but the problem is arising when i am submitting then i want the post value and answer should be match and and inside the if condition i want to increment the counter by 1 but it increment by 1 at once and after its not increment so please help me some one and above is my code

Comment: Could you show us some more, since what you have shown us is not enough.

Comment: Try declaring $answer before if()

Comment: Hello Umair the main moto is to when page is submit then $_POST['ans'] == $_POST['quiz'] if condition is true then i want counter should be ++

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string comparison operators.
"==" just compares two strings and "===" will compare two strings with datatype